# Web API return XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to display the returned data as xml, but it returns in plain text.  I've this code:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
context.Response.Write("<pre>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(writer) + "</pre>");
```

I'am using this :

```
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                            {

... write the xml

}
```

... and create the XML.

This is how I send: `context.Response.Write("<pre>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(writer) + "</pre>");`

How can i return XML in RAW with tags and all?

Comment: What do you mean by trying to display? Is this in a browser? Please provide more information on your client, and expected results

Comment: yes it is that! it must be displayed in browser, like if you're calling an API and return the data in xml

Comment: Many browsers displays XML as plain text typically, so what's the issue?

Comment: i want to display tags and every thing, xml in raw!

Comment: So why do you add a <pre> etc. ? It's not a valid XML, just remove that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HttpConfiguration.Formatters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpconfiguration.formatters%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) contains various formatters to serialize your model.  Instead of writing directly to Response, consider your action to return a model or `XDocument`, and then make sure that you have `XmlFormatter` set in `HttpConfiguration.Formatters` to actually serialize it as XML.

Comment: Your answer is referring to Web API, the question was about MVC

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer Please see title of the post: _"**Web API** return XML"_

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer That said, I did change tag to a wrong one, and just updated to use tag `asp.net-web-api`.  That is a needed correction :)

Comment: Note that XML formatter is in the formatters collection by default. If you always want to display XML regardless of Accept header, you will need to remove the json formatter for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly the right answer in Web API is to either do content negotiation as @LB2 is suggesting.

If we look at the way you are doing this there are a few things that are incorrect.

1. You are trying to use HttpContext.Current to write directly to the output, although this works it's not a recommended practice because your pretty much bypass the whole pipeline, and lose many potential benefits of Web API.
2. The following line:

`context.Response.Write("<pre>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(writer) + "</pre>");`

Doesn't write any XML out, and basically makes the XML invalid. If you removed it things will start to seemingly work.

1. The real alternative is either to follow LB2's suggestion, though it's not very easy to suppress content negotiation for one action. Another (the official recommended) approach is to do the following.

   ```
   public HttpResponseMessage GetOrder()
   {
       // Sample object data
       Order order = new Order();
       order.Id = "A100";
       order.OrderedDate = DateTime.Now;
       order.OrderTotal = 150.00;

       // Explicitly override content negotiation and return XML
       return Request.CreateResponse<Order>(HttpStatusCode.OK, order, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
   }
   ```

See this link for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/02/25/content-negotiation-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api-beta-part-1.aspx (**Note**: This is an old blog post and needs to be updated to latest version)