# Need Web api to return XML for one controller and JSON for other controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

hi we have a running web api application which return json for web application.
now we need to integrate this same application for a new module with an other application, which can receive or pass xml only. so now we need to return json for our currenly running web app and xml for that outer application.

Is it possible that we can return xml response from one controller without altering existing application. so that it will not impact on our existing web app.

i have search and found this solution [How to force ASP.NET Web API to return JSON or XML data based on my input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975811/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-or-xml-data-based-on-my-input) and working, but this need a query string to pass every time. we can not modify our existing app.

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
    new QueryStringMapping("type", "json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
    new QueryStringMapping("type", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
```

please suggest some solution for the same. Also please suggest how to receive data which will come in xml format to web api from outer application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Default new module to Jason to work with existing application, and send command in new application to switch to XML.

Comment: but switching application to xml is at Global level, even if i set response to xml based on a condition for new module.. If there is any other request comes from current web app.. then application will send xml instead of json as we already have switched the response type.. as a result current application will stop working.. :(

Comment: Default every new connection to Jason then it will always work with existing application.

Comment: how can we do that ?

Comment: Run code on the solution you found.  Run the Jason when your application starts.  Then send command for xml when you need xml.

Comment: You should be able to rely on the `Accept` HTTP header. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574797.aspx

Comment: yes @howcheng, i am doing with that approach now...