# WEB API returning data in both JSON and XML as per my supply parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want a web api to return both data in XML as well as Json as per my requirement.Is there any way to do this a single web api method.

Comment: Looks like someone may have already [solved this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19978996/2679750)

Answer (score 2):

The client can tell Web API what to return by supplying an [Accept Header](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation).

To request a JSON response (which I believe is also the default when no Accept Header is present), you'd specify something like:

```
Accept: application/json
```

To request an XML response, you'd specify something like:

```
Accept: application/xml
```

Comment: Hi David can you please tell me how to test this thing Postman client and where to change the option in postman client.

Comment: @DebendraDash: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests  There's a tab called "Headers".  You'd specify headers there.