# Webapi returns JSON in string XML

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have developed WebAPI for mobile which should return JSON and it is working fine returning JSON but JSON comes under XML.

Below is my code and screenshot.

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

"result" is my response class in which I am filling data. I tried with JavaScriptSerializer and JsonConvert of Newsoft but failed.

[image: Json returned in XML]

How can I get it work with simple string in JSON?

Comment: Try setting `Response.ContentType = "application/json";`  [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and   [application/json](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json) and   [RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159)

Comment: Thank you but where I need to do that?

Comment: You need to do it before any data is sent from the server on the server. What seems pretty standard is to add code to accept a new get flag to determine the format. If flag is not set, then render as whatever you choose as default.  eg   `https://example.com/api/foo?type=json`

Comment: Do not return a JSON string. Just return the the result instance and the client can decide to get it as JSON or XML

Comment: @Samuel - I tried it and json gets converted but shows in XML as shown in above image.

Comment: @SirRufo Client is actually from mobile devices so they expect JSON as string.

Comment: The your client should set a header in the request that it will accept json. That is the whole story. WepApi can return both JSON or XML and let the client decide which one

Comment: This link might help if you are developing the web api from the ground up [Force web api to return plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581697/is-there-a-way-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-return-plain-text)  (just change plain text to `application/json`).  If you are using a pre-built framework, then you will need to check it's docs / modify it's code base / or scrap it.

Comment: Show the entire API method. Is it `public string Get()`?

Comment: This link here, may help in the event you ALWAYS want json > [Always return json IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629144/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-always-return-json)

Comment: BTW Internet Explorer will only accept XML by default. It is a very bad practice to test a WebApi with a browser. Use f.i. Postman (Chrome Application) to really test the WebApi

Comment: @Samuel, Thank you, it worked.  Also this url helped..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975811/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-or-xml-data-based-on-my-input

Comment: Guys, keep do down voting even if question is right and rightly described.

Comment: I never downvoted your question

Comment: Your question is not "right and righly described", relevant code is missing as I pointed out in my previous comment. If you followed that link from @Samuel and applied it, your API will be returning JSON, but that JSON will be a JSON string (`" { \"IsError\":0, \"Message\":\"City List\", ... "`), which is definitely not what you're looking for.

Comment: @CodeCaster, If question do not describe problem and people are not able to understand then you can say relevant code is missing - It is already there. Whatever part of code is required to make people understand it is there.. if you do not understand and review detailed code then its your problem.

Comment: The relevant part of this problem is the return type of the method, which you don't show. You're the one having a trivial question, and I've dealt with Web API more than enough to know what code is relevant. Also, as @SirRufo said, you don't need to do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` yourself, which is also part of the problem at hand.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I apologize and will take care next time. Thank you for making me aware. I really appreciate your time and comment on my question.

Comment: I'm sure you don't, but I really don't care about that. Again, if you apply the solution from that link or from the answer below, you are going to run into a new problem, being that your client cannot parse the JSON. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: So you mean the solution in this link wont work? It is returning as a string in JSON. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975811/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-or-xml-data-based-on-my-input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131413/discussion-between-k-s-and-codecaster).

Comment: i had modified my answer it is not worked yet?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have converted your only method return type to json and not the whole data(response data) to Json format. For returning whole response data to Json, add following syntax to your `WebApiConfig.cs` Class.

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Since Web Api sends all response data to XML by default. So you need to remove default `XMLFormatter` from `WebApiConfig.cs` class.

For better understanding of `MediaTypeFormatters` please have a look on this video tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNzgXjqqIjI&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=6

**UPDATE**

Dont serialize object in method. remove `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and return your object. Simply add above syntax in WebAppconfig.cs file.

Comment: This is not the answer. The OP is returning a **string** from their method. If the OP adds this, their API wil respond with JSON... but the JSON itself **will be a string**. So instead of `{ "foo" : "bar"}`, the response will be `"{ \"foo\" : \"bar\" }"`.

Comment: he need to remove this JsonConvert.SerializeObject from return type.

Comment: Hi Rajput, Thank you for the answer - I have applied the same thing as per my comment but applied json formatting using HttpwebRequest.