# Setting Response Type in Http Request in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am currently working on migrating our application from Angular 4 to Angular 5. I have a file which handles any post request and the post method looks like this:

```
public post = (data: any, url = '', header: any = null, mapToJson = false): any => {
        if (mapToJson) {
            return this.commonHttpService.post(url, data, header)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .map((response: Response) => response.json());
        } else {
            return this.commonHttpService.post(url, data, header)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .map((response: Response) => response);
        }
    }
```

It is making a call to the common http service method which is written in other file where I am creating a Http Request and appending the headers, params and options to the request. In the options we need to mention the response type, so I have added 'json' as response type. But some of the web services might return text or blob or any other content. The following is the way I have declared options in the request:

```
 httpOptions = {
                body: body,
                headers: req.headers,
                observe: 'response',
                params: params,
                reportProgress: false,
                responseType: 'json',
                withCredentials: true,

            };
    request = this.http.request('POST', url, httpOptions);
```

So when I am getting the response type as 'Text' or 'Blob' then the mapping is failing.It looks for a json structure but since I am getting the response as “Success”,I get an error about parsing. Is there any way we can specify multiple response types in the options. Like for 'responseType' inside httpOptions I would like to pass multiple values like 'json' | 'text' | 'blob'. Or Can we specify the response type dynamically? I have searched for answers online and was not able to find a better approach for this.

Comment: You should have multiple HTTP REST End point to support different response type based on the request received. /*.json should be handled by a different method in a controller than /*.xml, however they can internally call the same business logic. The interface should be different.

Comment: @PrabinPaudel - no they shouldn't. There are plenty ways to return different response formats from the same endpoint based on headers, route or query parameters, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975811/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-or-xml-data-based-on-my-input) for example. There's no need to introduce another endpoint for response formatting only.

Comment: @Valla, "mapping is failing" is not very informative. Please add error message or detailed description of what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Alexander I have just edited the question with the errors that I am facing when the return type is “Text”.

Comment: I don't think there is a universal translator of meta data between json, xml and text. Esp. with text I don't think it is going to be easy.

Comment: @Valla did you ever figure out how to get it working? I am having the same issue, but can't figure out what is the best way to proceed.

Comment: @Alexander: We followed an approach where the call to the web service would specify what type of data it would be expecting. For example in the above code for the post method we added one more parameter called responseType and set it to true by default. If any other web api is expecting text or blob then they would pass the type which would be passed to this post method and it would work fine.